# Battery Backed SRAM (and Digital Forensics)

Tags: forensics, storage, memory

1. Is it feasible to create a portable battery powered drive out of RAM that could sustain its data via the charge of a battery? From my understanding it doesn't require much power.

Combining this with drive encryption. I see this as being a highly effective method of securely transporting data, that in the event of emergency could be fairly rapidly (Around five minutes according to [research](https://citp.princeton.edu/research/memory/media/) at Princeton University) erased by removing the charge from the volatile memory.

2. Do you know of any current volatile memory implementation that could achieve such a result?

Comment: Yes, but SRAM is expensive, and DRAM requires a modest amount of power.

Comment: You're a decade or more too late.  The solution you're asking about was called the Palm Pilot.  There were even programs allowing them to be used as removable storage.  =)

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly feasible. Current RAM only holds its storage while power is applied to it, so doing that in a mobile device is no different to doing it in a computer.

And you are right - turning the power off will lose all data on the drive in a short time frame.

All common RAM implementations can do this. All you are wanting to do is scale down from something you could do right now with a laptop to just the RAM.